# Mat::convertTo does not work with OpenMP

Tags: c++, opencv, openmp

I use `Mat::convertTo()` in parallel region, it does not convert matrix data to the specific type. But I tested with other functions e.g. `cv::threshold()`, `cv::imshow()`. It works fine. I don't know what's wrong. Please see my code below :

```
    // Mat dst is CV_32FC1 
    if( dst.type() != CV_8UC1)
    {   
        int rows = dst.rows;
        #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
        {
            int numt = omp_get_num_threads();
            int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
            int start = tid*(rows/numt); 
            int end = (tid+1)*(rows/numt);
            if( tid == (numt-1))
            {
                end = rows;
            }

            Mat tmp = dst.rowRange(start, end);
            tmp.convertTo(tmp, CV_8UC1); 
    }
```

The parallel region is executed, but dst's type is still CV_32FC1. What's the problem in my code? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regard,
Nan

Comment: This cannot work since you're not changing the type of `dst` anywhere. There is also a brace missing in the code.

Comment: Thanks @macs, but I still don't clear about your suggestion. Could you guide me a piece of code or something? Since the `Mat::rowRange()` create new header for row span of `dst`. So if I convert type of `tmp`, why the `dst` type is still the old one. Sorry for the nonsense question. I'm new to opencv. :)

Comment: That is because you are creating a copy of `dst.rowRange`. So, when changing the type of `tmp` you are not changing the type of `dst`. It would also be helpful if you'd provide some more code. Right now the algorithm makes not really sense to me.

Comment: @macs This is all the code that related to the problem. Thanks to you, now I'm a bit clear with this. I just want to split the image data for each thread to execute without cloning anything. Is there any idea to do this?

Comment: You should execute the function, that uses this data, directly  within your parallel environment. Each thread performs calculation on `tmp` and when it's done the output data has to be merged. The merged result can be converted again to the datatype you want. Makes sense to you?

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I might need to recode it then. It's clear now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all the functions operating on Mat's check the size and type of the destination Mat's. If they are the same, they use them. So, if you threshold a Mat with

```
threshold(src, src, ...);
```

It will be processed **in-place**

But, if the destination mat is of different size, type, number of channels, etc, it will alloc a new one. In your example:

```
tmp.convertTo(tmp, CV_OTHER_TYPE);
```

now you suppose that the dst, which is actually the source for tpm, will be changed:

```
dst(tmp_region_ofInterest).convertTo(dst(region));
```

But it actually expands to

```
Mat  tmp2(tmp.size, CV_OTHER_SIZE);
tmp.convertTo(tmp2,...);
tmp = tmp2;
```

And after the function exits, your tmp is not anymore a region of dst.

Reason is simple: first, you cannot change type in place, and you cannot change type of a partial matrix. What do you want to happen? Have matrix (continuous space in the memory), filled with a mix of `unsigned char` and `float`? Because this will happen, at least at some moment when processing.

So, always check in the doc if a given function operates in place, and if it operates on regions of interest, and if it can operate in place on regions of interest. And also use the common sense to fill the missing gaps in the official doc.